# TCP Implementation in Micrsoft Windows XP + 7

Tags: windows, tcp

I'm looking for the TCP implementation in MS Windows, especially for Windows XP and 7 in case they are different.

To be more specific, I'm interested in the following parts of the TCP implementation:

- Congestion control

  - Slow-start
  - Congestion avoidance
  - fast retransmit
  - fast recovery
- Window size

I'm curios especially in respect to congestion control optimized algorithms in respect to wireless links, such as Westwood(+), Vegas, etc.

I do not expect the implementation to be available, but I hope that information exists what optimizations to the original RFC TCP protocol have been added in the years (if any). I do expect optimizations in respect to wireless links due to the wide spread of wifi networks. Maybe you can point me in the right direction where to search or even better already have an answer. Please add references to your answers if possible.

I appreciate your help. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft writes its own congestion control, a fact that has caused some grief with interoperability over the years.

Windows Vista and higher introduced [Compound TCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_TCP). The principle difference from standards-based Vegas being that it maintains two congestion windows instead of one for better responsiveness to network conditions.

- http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=70189 <-- a Microsoft Research paper (2005) on CTCP, which should have implementation details.
- http://academic.research.microsoft.com/Paper/1820611.aspx <-- another Microsoft Research paper (2004), published in a journal, describing CTCP and the problems it solves.

CTCP support is available in Windows XP 64 [as a hotfix](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/949316), though I don't believe it ships by default with any service-pack level. XP 32 doesn't have CTCP support available.

Windows XP supports standards based congestion control such as Reno and Vegas.